# Building app to upload CSV to Oracle 12c database via Apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I'v been asked to create an app in Oracle Apex that will allow me to drop a CSV file.  The file contains a list of all active physicians and associated info in my area.  I do not know where to begin! Requirements:

-after dropping CSV file to apex, remove unnecessary columns
-edit data in each field, ie if phone# > 7 characters and begins with 1, remove 1. Or remove all special characters from a column.
-The CSV contains physicians of every specialty, I only want to upload specific specialties to the database table.

I have a small amount of SQL experience from Uni, and I know some HTML and CSS, but beyond that I am lost.  Please help!

Began tutorial on Oracle-Apex.  Created upload wizard on a dev environment

1. User drops CSV file to apex
2. Apex edits columns to remove unneccesary characteres
3. Only uploads specific columns from CSV file
4. Only adds data when column "Specialties" = specific specialties
5. Does not add redundant data (physician is already located in table, do nothing)
6. Produces report showing all new physicians added to table

Answer (score 1):

Huh, you're in deep trouble as you have to do some job using a tool you don't know at all, with limited knowledge of SQL language. Yes, *it is said* that Apex is simple to use, but nonetheless ... you have to know at least *something*. Otherwise, as you said, you're lost.

See if the following helps.

- there's the CSV file
- create a table in your database; its description should match the CSV file. Mention all columns it contains. Pay attention to datatypes, column lengths and such

  - this table will be "temporary" - you'll use it every day to load data from CSV files: first you'll delete all it contains, then load new rows
- using Apex "Create page" Wizard, create the "Data loading" process. Follow the instructions (and/or read documentation about it). Once you're done, you'll have 4 new pages in your Apex application
- when you run it, you should be able to load CSV file into that *temporary* table

That's the first stage - successfully load data into the database. Now, the second stage: fix what's wrong.

- create another table in the database; it will be the "target" table and is supposed to contain only data you need (i.e. the subset of the *temporary* table). If such a table already exists, you don't have to create a new one.
- create a stored procedure. It will read data from the *temporary* table and edit everything you've mentioned (remove special characters, remove leading "1", ...)

  - as you have to skip physicians that already exist in the target table, use `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`
- then insert "clean" data into the *target* table

That stored procedure will be executed after the Apex loading process is done; a simple way to do that is to create a button on the last page which will - when pressed - call the procedure.

The final stage is the report:

- as you have to show new physicians, consider adding a column (into the target table) which will be a timestamp (perhaps `DATE` is enough, if you'll be doing it once a day) or `process_id` (all rows inserted in the same process will share the same value) so that you could distinguish newly added rows from the old ones
- the report itself would be an *Interactive report*. Why? Because it is easy to create and lets you (or end users) to adjust it according to their needs (filter data, sort rows in a different manner, ...)

Good luck! You'll need it.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed -- a roadmap! I've found another post here showing how to create the initial table, so that's done. I've also created the import wizard.  So now that I can import everything into the temp table, I'm working on merging the required data to the final table while eliminating all of the unnecessary data.  Again, thanks!!!!